# What are these power connectors called and can I use extension cables for a footwarmer?

Tags: power, identification, connector, cables, power-connector

I'd like to know what these connectors are called, so I can locate them online and purchase extension cables. I have looked in a number of places and cannot identify them or locate cables. So if anyone knows what to look for and/or places to look, I'd be grateful. The only codes I can find are "XG" on the splitter.

My ultimate plan is to insert two short (say 2-3") M-F extension cables between the split cables from the control unit and the warmer? I want to be able to mount the control unit on my desk, but the shortness of the cables (20" total) prevents that, forces the control unit to remain on the floor near the footwarmer itself.

Is there any reason I can't or shouldn't do that? Is there a reason for the short run (20") from the controller to the warmer, other than perhaps availability of parts?

Background...

These cables connect a footwarmer to the control unit (on/off, temp, timer) which is itself connected to a standard US two-prong 60V power cable. They appear to be polarized by the notch on one side. The female connectors are about 8 x 14 mm. Well, male-female is ambiguous here -- it refers to the pins/holes, not to the connectors (the female connector has two male pins).

As the second photo shows, there is a 16" cable with a splitter coming from the control unit with two of the females. The other side of the control unit goes to the standard power plug. The split cables connect to two 4" cables with male connectors on the warmer itself. One split cable is connected and the other loose in the photo.

Thanks.

[image: the M and F connectors]

[image: whole rig]

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Macbook_Charger_Extension_4_2019-05-15.jpg/1920px-Macbook_Charger_Extension_4_2019-05-15.jpg

---

Addendum -- I cannot find these connectors at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets

nor at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320

On the latter, the C7/C8 comes closest, but that one has a notch on both sides and is thus not polarized. The non-standard C7P is square at one end. The MacBook connector on that site looks pretty close, but it has an altogether non-standard extra pin for grounding and to secure the adapter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community -- I reorganized the post -- I hope it now satisfies your request.

Comment: Might be proprietary. Consider reaching out to the manufacture for an authorized cable. If you get the wrong one, the connection could be compromised which is a fire hazard.

Comment: These are probably moulded so I'm not sure what good it will do you to find them. Depending on current draw and voltage required, extending cables may or may not work in case of voltage drop. These may just be forwarding the unregulated VAC line voltage or it could be a lower one. What will probably work no matter is just to cut the damn things off, replace with a sufficiently high current/voltage rated connector, then solder in a thicker copper wire than what's there presently. Naturally you shouldn't be touching this unless you have soldering experience and know basic electronics.

Comment: Test #1 is to take your multimeter and beep test from the 230VAC connector to the 2 pins in the outgoing connector. If there's no resistance in between then it's just 230VAC all the way.

Answer (score 1):

Those are custom connectors. You won't find them for sale.

Option 1 (the smart one):

1. Plug the 110 Vac plug into a readily available 110 Vac extension cord.
2. Done

Option 2 (a better approach that your approach):

1. Get wire some permanent wire splices (such as [crimp butt splices](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=8e2660c4d8666842&q=crimp+butt+splices&tbm=isch&source=lnms&prmd=isvhnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1pKW9jJeEAxXxAjQIHUglCl4Q0pQJegQIDhAB&biw=1625&bih=822&dpr=1))
2. Get a length of two-conductor cable
3. Cut the cord of your product
4. Splice the length of two-conductor cable into the cord and secure with the wire splices

Option 3 (closest to your intent):

1. Find a readily-available connector that has plugs of both genders
2. Cut the cords of your product
3. Install the readily-available plugs onto the cords
4. Get a length of two-conductor cable
5. Make out of it an extension cable terminated with more of those readily-available plugs

Comment: Yup, I get the point -- custom connectors. A 110VAC extension cord doesn't help, because the controller is still only 20" from the warmer, so it has to stay on the floor. 

Not worth the surgical options suggested (though thanks). 

My minimalist solution -- put a small adhesive plastic pad on the controller's on/off button so I can find and operate it with my big toe!